# Why aren't my accounts / keystore files showing up in Mist / Etheruem Wallet?

Tags: accounts, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I recently upgraded to 0.7.4 (Windows) and all my accounts are gone. In the keystore folder, I can see what I think are my keys. However they are not being auto loaded.

When I went from 0.6.1 to 0.7.2 there was no issue, it would automatically find and import them.

Any idea or is this a bug that should be reported ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple reasons keystore files may not be showing up in Mist.

1. You are still syncing and/or watching a heavy contract like The DAO contract, which is making Mist hang or lag and so it hasn't shown them yet.
2. The file names do not include the address of the account. [Here is more information](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-delete-address-field-from-the-ethereum-key-file/3897), but basically your keystore files should be named `UTC--2016-05-13T04-31-42.137297157Z--f367f6e5f828fe85f5d95839ebb3f005f2368182`. If you remove the address from the keystore file, it will not display in the Mist UI.
3. The folder that Mist is reading from is not the folder that contains your keystore files. To see where Mist is reading from, go to "Account" -> "Backup" -> "Accounts" and see what folder is opens. Confirm that there are keystore files inside there and the names contain the address of the account.

Comment: I created an issue here https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/761#issuecomment-224081943
and basically what i found is that the wallet files are getting placed in ANOTHER folder (different path). The observations in issue 761 should provide more information.